# On the real and finite field rank of a $0/1$ matrix - II

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, finite-fields, symmetric-groups, nonnegative-matrices

Let $M\in\{-\ell,\dots,-1,0,+1,\dots,+\ell\}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix of rank $r$ where $\ell\geq1$ such that there is a permutation matrix in $\{0,1\}^{m\times m}$ of order $2\ell$.

Fix a permutation matrix $T$ of order $2\ell$.

Consider the matrix $f(M)\in\{0,+1\}^{mn\times mn}$ where $0$ in $M$ is replaced by $m\times m$ all $0$ matrix, $a$ in $M$ is replaced by $T^{2a}$ and $-a$ is replaced by $T^{-2a-1}$ at every $a\in\{1,2,\dots,\ell\}$.

Example at $m=2$:

$0$ is replaced by $\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$, $+1$ is replaced by $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $-1$ is replaced by $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

> 1. How is the the real rank of the new matrix related to $m,\ell$ and $r$? Is there a precise bound?

> 2. Is the $\mathbb F_2$ rank of the new matrix related to $m,\ell$ and $r$? Is there a precise bound?

[On the real and finite field rank of a $0/1$ matrix - I](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387067/on-the-real-and-finite-field-rank-of-a-0-1-matrix-i)

Comment: Perhaps you should include a link to the other question in each of the two questions you have posted about these matrices?